# Using HSQLDB with encryption

Tags: encryption, hsqldb

We are creating a self contained system with Spring Boot and for persistence we are  using HSQLDB.

Does HSQLDB provide an option to encrypt the data being stored ?

If it does not, is there any other solution to encrypt the data for Spring Boot and HSQLDB combination ?

Answer (score 1):

HSQLDB supports database persistence encryption. See the Guide:

http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_encrypted_database

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21684366)

Comment: The question has a short answer that is given. The details are in official documentation and a link is given.